# Passing Integer arguments from Java function to JNI function returning garbage values?

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I am calling a JNI function with `int` values as parameters. I am sending width and height as 800 and 480. But when I try to print these values in the JNI function I am getting 1 and 0 instead of 800 and 480. Why I am getting wrong values in JNI?

My JNI function call is:

```
findSquare(sourceImage.getNativeObjAddr(),
                        imageTaken.getNativeObjAddr(), 1, width, height);

public native void findSquare(long matAddrRgba, long matAddrDescriptor,
        int draw, int width, int height);
```

And the JNI function is:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL 
Java_info_androidhive_androidcameraapi_CameraMainActivity_findSquare(
        JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong addrRgba, jlong addrDescriptor, jlong addrSrc,
        jlong addrDst, jint draw, jint width, jint height);
```

Comment: Hi there !! You seem to be around for quite long time. Please take care of the formatting of the post yourself. Thank you. :-)

Comment: It seems like arguments in prototype and call function doesn't match. What happened with `addrSrc` and `addrDst`?

Comment: They are *not* matching. You have `(long, long, int, int, int)` on the Java side and `(jlong, jlong, jlong, jint, jint, jint)` on the JNI side. Reconcile this.

Comment: Actually it's even worse than that. You have five parameters in Java and seven in JNI, not counting the `JNIEnv*` and the `jobject.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The android and native method signatures don't match.

Your Java native method should look like this:

```
// added addrSrc, addrDst which were missing.
public native void findSquare(long matAddrRgba, long matAddrDescriptor, 
                              long addrSrc, long addrDst, int draw, int width, 
                              int height);
```

Comment: Iam getting Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1) exception while calling native method? Could you please help me?

Comment: This exception will arise if we try to use a vector of size 0(in my case). I've missed 'length(>0)' check while using it with for loop.